# discrete borel probability measure can approximate borel probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

what is the meaning of every Borel probability measure on a compact Hausdorff space is
the pointwise limit of a net of discrete probability measures, each having the
same barycenter?

Comment: Which one of the words causes trouble?

Comment: To understand "barycenter" you need more structure than "compact Hausdorff space" perhaps.  Maybe start with a simple case.  A Borel probability measure on $[0,1]$ with mean $1/2$ is the limit (in the narrow topology for measures) of a sequence of discrete probability measures, each having mean $1/2$.